How to declare plugin version as part of version catalog
How to declare plugin version as part of version catalog, so its dynamically loaded across projects. In the following case I want to load 4.10.0 from the version catalog
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'pmd'
    id 'io.sentry.jvm.gradle' version '4.10.0'
...
}


You can declare plugins in the [plugins] section:
libs.versions.toml:
[plugins]
sentry-gradle = { id = "io.sentry.jvm.gradle", version = "4.10.0" }

build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.sentry.gradle)
}


Edit:
To declare plugin in settings.gradle:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            plugin('sentry-gradle', 'io.sentry.jvm.gradle').version('4.10.0')
        }
    }
}

Edit2:
To only load version declared as "sentry-gradle" from the version catalog:
plugins {
    id 'io.sentry.jvm.gradle' version libs.versions.sentry.gradle
}


I use a build.gradle to declare my versionCatalog under catalog section and don't manipulate the toml file directly. If so what would be the syntax

Do you mean settings.gradle? I added an example for that. @user352290

No I didn't mean that, I meant the build.gradle corresponding to the version catalog itself

I made another edit. If this is not what you need could you provide more details on how exactly the version catalog implemented in your project? @user352290
